# Minizinc lazyfd solution ignores constraint

Tags: constraint-programming, minizinc

The problem is to find a schedule for some people to play golf (or whatever) in groups of a fixed size.
We have to guarantee that every player is only in one group at a time.

Here is my code:

```
int: gr;             % number of groups
int: sz;             % size of groups
int: we;             % number of weeks

int: n=gr*sz;        % number of players

set of int: G=1..gr; % set of group indices
set of int: P=1..n;  % set of players
set of int: W=1..we; % set of weeks

% test instance
gr = 2;
sz = 2;
we = 2;

array[G,W] of var set of P: X;
   %X[g,w] is the set of people that form group with index g in week w


% forall group x, |x| = sz
constraint forall (g in G, w in W) 
  (card (X[g,w]) = sz);

% one person cannot play in two groups simultaneously
constraint forall (g in G, w in W, p in X[g,w], g2 in (g+1..gr))
  (not(p in X[g2,w]));

solve satisfy;
```

My problem now is that if I use the G12 lazyfd solver, i.e.

```
$ minizinc -b lazy this.mzn
```

I get

```
X = array2d(1..2 ,1..2 ,[1..2, 1..2, 1..2, 1..2]);
----------
```

which seems to ignore my second constraint.
On the other hand, using G12 without the lazy option, i.e.

```
$ minizinc this.mzn
```

yields

```
X = array2d(1..2 ,1..2 ,[1..2, 1..2, 3..4, 3..4]);
----------
```

which is correct.
G12 MIP and Gecode also give a correct result.

How is this possible? And how can I use the lazy solver such that I can rely on it? Or is it just my installation that is messed up somehow?

Comment: looks like a `bug`, report it [here](https://github.com/MiniZinc/libminizinc/issues); any reason why you would not use a different engine other than `lazy`?

Comment: Performance was my reason, but I guess the performance comes from the bug... I had a more complicated example where only the lazy solver was able to solve it in a reasonable amount of time - at first I didn't realize it was the wrong solution!

Comment: On this example, the `fd` engine finds `36` different array arrangements in under 1 second, whereas the `lazy` engine finds `777` different arrangements. So, yes, it's due to the bug or some other intrinsic limitations of the engine itself which I am not aware of.

Comment: OK, for this means that I can't trust the `lazy` engine at all, since I don't really understand what the bug is. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

G12/lazyFD is known to be broken in various places. The problem is that the G12 solvers are no longer being developed and will most likely be removed from the distributions soon.

I would offer Chuffed as an alternative. Chuffed is FD solver written in C++ with lazy clause generation. It should be correct and will perform better then the G12 solver (at least when the solutions are correct).

Chuffed and other MiniZinc solvers can be found on the [software page of the MiniZinc website](http://www.minizinc.org/software.html).